# Create Second User Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use notification for send bulk email to users,
I have a list of 1000 emails as a JSON file (include :name and email),

because of that notification accept notifiable entities,

I very try for find a solution for do it,
I decide create a Model same of User Model , that I fill new User Mode with my emails , and pass it to notification facade,

but I dont find a solution for create new User Model,

can you help me,Please?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: just make an instance of the original user model with the email! and use that to send emails without presisting the data?

Comment: very thanks, can you help me more? can you write code for  instance of the original user model, Please?

Comment: Check my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best [solution](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) for you

```
Notification::route('mail', 'taylor@example.com')
            ->notify(new NotificationClass($users));
```

**Edit**

Other way is too Create instances of user model without presisting them

```
$users = [];

foreach ($usersList as $key => $user){
   $model = new App\User;
   $model->email = $user['email'];
   $model->name = $user['name'];

   $users[] = $model;
}

Notification::send($users, new NotificationClass($users));
```

I'm not sure if the name is required but u can ignore it i guess!

Comment: Yes, that's something related to ur own models, basically the problem is that it doesn't find a method data in the user instance! you should be able to fix that easly

Comment: very very Thanks Achraf, it Worked ,